# List sort is malfunctioning in python 3.7

Tags: python

I'm new to python and i was practicing to code something to calculate CDF (Cumulative Density Function), the code is below:

It works fine except in some cases when i input something like:
12-12-125-15-152-16-10

The reverse sorting doesn't get a correct sorting results.

```
# This is a trial to make an app for calculating the CDF for a set of numbers
# x = int(input("Please Enter the Number of Samples: "))  # x represents the number of samples
y = input("\nPlease Enter the samples separated by (-) with no spaces: ") # y represents the samples collection point
# print(y)
z = y.split("-")
x = len(z)
s = len(z)+1    # s represents the total sample space
print("\nThe number of samples is {} and the sample space is {} sample.\n".format(x,s))
# z.reverse()
z.sort(reverse=True)
# print(z)
# print(len(z))
ind = 0
for i in z:
    ind+= 1
    freq = (ind)/s
    print(i, freq, ind)
```

Expected sorting results:
152
125
16
15
12
12
10

Actual sorting results:
16
152
15
125
12 
12
10

Comment: You are sorting the strings, and `"16"` actually is greater than `"152"`. Perhaps you wanted to sort the numbers? If so you must convert to number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to convert str to int in list Z:
possible solution is to add `list(map(int, z))`

```
# This is a trial to make an app for calculating the CDF for a set of numbers
# x = int(input("Please Enter the Number of Samples: "))  # x represents the number of samples
y = input("\nPlease Enter the samples separated by (-) with no spaces: ") # y represents the samples collection point
# print(y)
z = y.split("-")
z = list(map(int, z))
x = len(z)
s = len(z)+1    # s represents the total sample space
print("\nThe number of samples is {} and the sample space is {} sample.\n".format(x,s))
# z.reverse()
z.sort(reverse=True)
# print(z)
# print(len(z))
ind = 0
for i in z:
    ind+= 1
    freq = (ind)/s
    print(i, freq, ind)
```

then the result is: 152 125 16 15 12 12 10

Comment: Appreciated Robert, that helped !!

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're comparing `str`s.

Please change `str` into `int`

```
# This is a trial to make an app for calculating the CDF for a set of numbers
# x = int(input("Please Enter the Number of Samples: "))  # x represents the number of samples
y = input("\nPlease Enter the samples separated by (-) with no spaces: ") # y represents the samples collection point
# print(y)
z = y.split("-")
x = len(z)
intList=[]
for char in z:
    intList.append(int(char))
print(intList)
intList.sort(reverse=True)
print(intList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions are fine. However if for some reason you wish to keep a `z` a list of strings, you can convert them in the sorting algorithm.

In your code, add a `key` to the `sort` method:

```
z.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
```

Strings will be converted to numbers only in the sorting process.